# Bandwidth of finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, cayley-graphs

For a generating set $S$ of a group $G$ denote by $\mathrm{Cay}(G,S)$ the corresponding Cayley graph.

For a finite graph $A$ denote by $\beta(A)$ its [bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_bandwidth).

**Question**: Has the "group bandwidth"

$$\beta(G):=\min_{S\subset G}\beta(\mathrm{Cay}(G,S))$$

of finite groups been studied?

Comment: The bandwidth is clearly minimized on a minimal generating set, i.e. a generating set which after removing any element is no longer a generating set. For $\mathbb F_p^n$, such a generating set is a basis, and in particular is unique up to automorphisms. In particular, for $p=2$, the relevant Cayley graph is a hypercube, so the bandwidth was determined by one of the results  mentioned on the Wikipedia page you link, i.e. Harper, L. (1966). "Optimal numberings and isoperimetric problems on graphs".https://doi.org/10.1016%2FS0021-9800%2866%2980059-5

Answer (score 4):

There is a well-known conjecture of Babai: suppose that $G$ is a finite, non-abelian, simple group. Suppose that $S$ is any generating set for $G$. Then the diameter of the resulting Cayley graph is at most $C \cdot \log(|G|)^c$ where $C$ and $c$ are constants that do not depend on anything.

This conjecture is very difficult, but has been resolved in some cases.  See the article *Growth in groups: ideas and perspectives* by Helfgott in the Bulletin of the AMS.

When the conjecture is true, then we get a lower bound on the bandwidth: when you lay the group out on the integers the distance between the largest and the smallest element is exactly $|G| - 1$. On the other hand, it only takes poly-log many edges to connect them in the Cayley graph. Thus some edge has layout length at least $|G| /(C \cdot \log(|G|)^c)$.

---

On the other hand, if $G$ is cyclic then the bandwidth of $G$ is one or two as $|G|$ is even or odd.